# Deny node access depending on field value

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to restrict the access to nodes of type article depending on a field value of the node. When I implement `hook_node_access()` it seems to have no effect on the node.

Even if I try to restrict the whole access it seems to have no effect.

```
function mymodule_node_access($node, $op, $account) {
  $type = $node->getType();
  if ($type == 'article') {
    return AccessResult::isForbidden;
  }
}
```

What's my mistake?

Answer (score 2):

With what user do you check the access, as stated in the [docs](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21node%21node.api.php/function/hook_node_access/8.2.x)

> The administrative account (user ID #1) always passes any access
>   check, so this hook is not called in that case. Users with the "bypass
>   node access" permission may always view and edit content through the
>   administrative interface.

***user 1 will always have access ..***

Make sure to check with an anonymous or regular user.